# Preparing an Android button with a non-standard inner glow?

Tags: android, button

I'm working on a project where I have to prepare for my dev team a large button with an oval-shaped inner glow in the center. I'm familiar with 9-patch and would otherwise normally apply it to this button, which is a full screen-width rectangle, however the button has a "glow" in the center which I was specifically asked not to generate using code, but by image(the glow has a unique shape). If I apply 9-patch to this and it scales up, I'm assuming the glow will not look as nice when it gets stretched. Has anyone ever encountered a button like this, and if so, how did you resolve implementing it? I am also interested in learning about the development process for this, to better help me communicate with my dev team, and for my own  personal interest.

In summary, how do I prepare an Android button with a unique inner texture that does not repeat edge-to-edge, using 9-patch and/or another technique?

Answer (score 0):

I think 9-patch technique doesn't help you much here in this scenario because it has some irregular shape and textures.